# How to find the version of importlib-metadata and importlib-resources?

Tags: pip, python-3.8, python-importlib

I have installed python3.8 base package in RHEL docker container.
I am using **python3.8.6**

I tried below stuff, but couldn't find versions of them,

```
[root@6d205ce6c52d /]# python3.8 --version
Python 3.8.6
[root@6d205ce6c52d /]# 
[root@6d205ce6c52d /]# 
[root@6d205ce6c52d /]# pip3.8 list | grep import
zope.deferredimport          4.4        
[root@6d205ce6c52d /]# 
[root@6d205ce6c52d /]# 
[root@6d205ce6c52d /]# pip3.8 show importlib-metdata
WARNING: Package(s) not found: importlib-metdata
[root@6d205ce6c52d /]# 
[root@6d205ce6c52d /]# 
[root@6d205ce6c52d /]# pip3.8 show importlib-resources
WARNING: Package(s) not found: importlib-resources
[root@6d205ce6c52d /]# 
[root@6d205ce6c52d /]# 
[root@6d205ce6c52d /]# 
[root@6d205ce6c52d /]# 
[root@6d205ce6c52d /]# python3.8
Python 3.8.6 (default, Jan 22 2021, 11:41:28) 
[GCC 8.4.1 20200928 (Red Hat 8.4.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import importlib.metadata
>>> 
>>> dir(importlib.metadata)
['ConfigParser', 'Distribution', 'DistributionFinder', 'EntryPoint', 'FastPath', 'FileHash', 'MetaPathFinder', 'MetadataPathFinder', 'PackageNotFoundError', 'PackagePath', 'PathDistribution', 'Prepared', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'abc', 'collections', 'csv', 'distribution', 'distributions', 'email', 'entry_points', 'files', 'functools', 'import_module', 'io', 'itertools', 'metadata', 'operator', 'os', 'pathlib', 'posixpath', 're', 'requires', 'starmap', 'suppress', 'sys', 'version', 'zipfile']
>>> print(importlib.metadata.version)
<function version at 0x7f7b423400d0>
>>>
>>>
```

There is no attribute as `__version__` for importlib.metadata / importlib.resources

Answer (score 0):

`importlib-metadata` is a package from stdlib: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html

The same for `importlib.resources`:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources.

The [`importlib-resources` from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-resources/) is a backport of Python standard library `importlib.resources` module for older Pythons.

Comment: Yes.

importlib.metadata is a library that provides for access to installed package metadata. **Built in part on Python’s import system**, this library intends to replace similar functionality in the entry point API and metadata API of pkg_resources.




I wanted to know how to find the version of those.....
1. ```importlib.metadata```
2. ```importlib.resources```

Comment: @RAHULRAJDN They're parts of Python standard library. Their versions are irrelevant, the only relevant version is the version of the very Python.

Comment: Here I observe version associated with both ```importlib.metadata``` and ```importlib.resources```


https://pypi.org/project/importlib-metadata/
https://pypi.org/project/importlib-resources/


Although, they come a part of python base package as in my case, they still have their specific versions right ?

Comment: @RAHULRAJDN Depending on how you have installed them. When installed with the rest of stdlib they **do not have** their specific versions.